# Google Sheets using SWITCH inside an ArrayFormula. Wonky formula, looking for something as efficient but more elegant

Tags: switch-statement, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

The below Google Sheets formula achieves my intended objective but I feel like the two constructed arrays {} with the repeated ranges are something less than elegant. I'm using a `SWITCH` statement for performance reasons as I don't want to perform the `VLOOKUP` on that matrix more than once when testing against at least 3 possible conditions.

```
=ArrayFormula(SWITCH(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:C100, G2:H16, 2, 0), -1),
 "F", {D1:D100, D1:D100, D1:D100}, "M", {E1:E100, E1:E100, E1:E100}, 0))
```

Background: a configured workflow of 3 reviewers in range `A1:C100` contains a combination of either Male or Female employees (`VLOOKUP` to get gender). If reviewer is female return a value in range `D1:D100` otherwise if male return a value in `E1:100`. The workflow may also contain blank or "N/A" for which a value of 0 is returned.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E5YqCLJOHfeY32GAeDk-1yMEgxxMGS1iAqkvn5l8laE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    VLOOKUP(A1:C100, G1:H15, 2, 0) = "F",
      D1:D100,
      E1:E100
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In simplifying my example for this post I left out that the workflow may also contain  blanks or N/A values such that there are more than just two possible values for evaluation. I've updated my original formula to reflect this.

Comment: @PaulM just enclose the whole `IF(..)` statement in `IFNA(..., 0)` in case `VLOOKUP` cannot find anything.

Comment: This is getting very close to replicating the functionality of my Switch statement. The only additional nuance is that because the workflow has data validation (drop down list of selectable names), N/A does return a value from the VLOOKUP so using the IF statement logic it will be treated as a "M" since is does not match to "F". This is where I liked the funtionality of SWITCH as I could say match F or match M else default to 0.